# Question on Hölder continuity with exponent $\frac12$ and its application

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory

I'm having a bit of trouble with the following problem:

> Suppose $f$ is square integrable on $\mathbb{R}$. Define $$F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt$$ Show that $F$ is Hölder continuous with exponent $\frac12$.

I tried to prove it directly by starting with plugging in $F$ into $|F(x) - F(y)|$ but got nowhere. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Just use Holder inequality with $p=q=2$

$|F(x) - F(y)|=|\int_y^x f(t) dt|\le \sqrt{\int_y^x |f|^2 dt}\sqrt{\int_y^x 1 dt}\le C|x-y|^{\frac{1}{2}} $ with $C=\sqrt{\int_\mathbb{R} |f|^2 dt}$